# UITableViewCell accessoryType.Checkmark messes with my .Center textAlignment

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview, swift2, uikit

As the title says. I have a tableview filled with some cells which have a textAlignment = .Center. Whenever I select a cell, the checkmark is showing up as it should be, but at the same time it messes my alignment of the text so the text is pushed by a small offset to the left. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by adding an accessory view, the size of the cell used to calculate center is reduced by that much, as there are now 2 separate views being rendered in that cell. Without seeing your cell (and/or code) and how your labels are laid out, I can't comment on a specific solution.